# Text weight changing on fade in and out

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, bxslider

I'm using a basic fade slider for a few testimonials on a site I'm working on, and the text is fading from one to another just fine. However as soon as the 'latest text' loads, the weight increases. I have checked my CSS and removed all weight classes. Any idea what could be causing this? Example of work is here: http://theapsgroup.org/slide.html

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: I cannot see any difference in font sizes when viewing your slider in Firefox. However at a guess is the font-weight being applied in the javascript

Comment: What do you mean when you say "weight increases"? Are you referring to the font-weight? I looked at your example and I am not sure what your issue is.

Comment: @DreamTeK I have just checked Firefox and other browsers, it appears to be a problem with Safari only. So you would recommend removing any font weights set in Javascript?

Comment: @Liam You would basically have to see if the script you're using supports Safari or not. Not all libraries/scripts care about 100% cross browser support.

Comment: @remyabel  do you know how I found out if a script is supported by certain browsers? Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I don't see any change. Every slide has text set to 'font-weight:normal'

Answer (score 0):

In your css you can overwrite these properties so you don't have to change the javascript.
Identify the element that is having the font weight appplied and try this.

```
theculprit{
    font-weight:400 !important;
}
```

Important will force this rule to override other rules but must be applied to the correct offending element.

**Alternatively Try**

I suspect the issue is not font-weight but the way Safari renders this font. Try Arial Font see if it persists.

Comment: Because it is happening to all text, I have applied it (beginning with the first paragraph and through to second) and Im afraid the problem persists ..

Comment: I suspect the issue is not font-weight but the way Safari renders this font. Try Arial Font see if it persists.

Comment: Still no luck I am afraid, I have removed the only font-weight I could find in all four scripts, changed the font to Arial and also added font-weight:400 !important; to all character styles. Very peculiar, it is strange however that when I change a certain background, the problem does cease. It's not ideal but I guess I could work my way around it ..

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
html { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
```